# Java Vector - all objects get index -1

Tags: java, vector, indexing

i have a very strange problem with java Vector.

I am working on a task - EShop with java, for this i have 3 Vectors with goods, customers and workers.

All objects i add to customers and workers Vector get index -1, and i was actually unable to find anything like this in any guide.

The actual problem about it - i cant delete any of that objects from my Vector.

I can still get the full list of that objects, i can change them, save them or load from .txt or .ser. They can use shop funktions like buying, so they are actually IN the Vector. But because of -1 index i cant delete them.

Literally the same code from the same project etc, just with other object type (goods) is working perfectly, so i have no idea even where i should look for a reason of this mistake.

```
public class MitarbeiterVerwaltung {
    private Vector<Mitarbeiter> mitarbeiterListe = new Vector<Mitarbeiter>();
    private PersistenceManager pm = new ObjectStreamPM();

public boolean einfuegeMitarbeiter(Mitarbeiter einMitarbeiter) throws PersonExistiertBereitsException{
    if (mitarbeiterListe.contains(einMitarbeiter))
        throw new PersonExistiertBereitsException(einMitarbeiter, "- in einfuegeMitarbeiter()");
    else
        return mitarbeiterListe.add(einMitarbeiter);
}

public void loescheMitarbeiter(Mitarbeiter einMitarbeiter){
    mitarbeiterListe.remove(einMitarbeiter);
}
```

The console output (object id, object nickname(first, second etc), index):

```
    public Vector<Mitarbeiter> getAlleMitarbeiter(){
        for(Mitarbeiter m : mitarbeiterListe){
        System.out.println(m.getKnummer()+ " "+m.getNickname()+" index:"+mitarbeiterListe.indexOf(m));
        }
        return mitarbeiterListe;
}
```

0 first index:-1

1 second index:-1

2 third index:-1

3 fourth index:-1

the class definition as asked below.

```
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3134247641351150211L;

        private String nickname;    
        private int knummer;
        private String passwort;        
        private String name;
        private PersonStatus status;

        public Person(String nickname, int knummer, String passwort,
                String name, PersonStatus status){
            this.nickname = nickname;
            this.knummer = knummer;
            this.passwort = passwort;
            this.name = name;
            this.status = status;


        }
```

public class Mitarbeiter extends Person {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -2689774445774446934L;

private double rabbat;
private transient WarenkorbVerwaltung warenkorb;

public Mitarbeiter(String nickname, int knummer, String passwort,
        String name, double rabbat){
    super (nickname, knummer, passwort, name, PersonStatus.Mitarbeiter);
    this.warenkorb = new WarenkorbVerwaltung();
    this.rabbat = rabbat;
}
```

setters, getters, toString, compare below. Doubt its important for the problem.

Solution foun - thanks to Smith_61 and others who pointed me to the equals method in the object classes. I really havent implemented it, thinking thet equals of the mother class (Person) will do. Adding equals to the Mitarbeiter class solved the problem.

```
public boolean equals (Object o){
    if(o instanceof Mitarbeiter)
        return ((this.getKnummer() == ((Mitarbeiter) o).getKnummer()) 
            && (this.getNickname().equals(((Mitarbeiter) o).getNickname())));
    else
        return false;

}
```

Comment: What is the definition of the Mitarbeiter class?

Comment: added it to the main post, no idea how to format code in comments

Comment: We need the definition of the whole class. I'm assuming you have overridden the equals method and we need to see that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Vector.indexOf(object)` internally makes a call to `equals` method of that object and checks if any element in vector returns `true`. So you need to override the `equals` method of `Mitarbeiter` class and do the comparison.

As mentioned by Smith, your code should return correct index if you have not overridden `equals` method. It seems that you have implemented equals method wrongly and that's why you are always getting `-1`.